# Listen, ... vs Look,

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the difference between:

> Look, you shouldn't ...
>
> Listen, ...

Is it true that the first one is more about your opinion, but the second one - about some news/information?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the choice between "literal" ***listen*** and "metaphoric" ***look*** has no implications for intended meaning in such contexts. It's entirely a stylistic choice. And both versions are only likely in casual *spoken* contexts, so there's no difference in "level of formality" either.

On the other hand, there ***is*** often a difference between these two possible *replies...*

> 1: *I **see** what you mean* (usually implies *...and **I agree** with you*)
> 2: *I **hear** what you say* (often implies ***...but I disagree***, or *there's more to it than that*).

---

EDIT: Idiomatically, it's "unnatural" to say *I **see** what you **say*** OR *I **hear** what you **mean***, so arguably I'm not really comparing like with like above. A better pair (where both versions are quite natural) might be...

> 1a: *I see what you're saying*
> 2a: *I hear what you're saying*

...where the same usage distinction applies (how likely is it to be followed by a "**but...**" caveat?).

Comment: As a native speaker, I 100% agree with your see/hear distinction, but I find it rather baffling that it even exists. This is something I would do subconsciously.

Comment: "I see", here, means more like "I see it now" or "I realize", I think. Consequently, it is an admission of fault. (I didn't see it before.) While I hear is jut "your words are reaching my ears, I see your point (see what I did here?) but it's not a realization to me, I'm still of my previous opinion.

Comment: @Zachiel that sums up it really well, thank you for adding that.